# WP display ACF value from all posts on a page

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I would like to create a page that displays 3 ACF Values in an alphabetized list. I have a custom post type ="product" and would like to display the following twi fields (Both are ACF text fields) 1. vendor_or_brand_name and 2. product_url

I can output all post titles from the product post type like this:

```
function output_product_list() {
    global $wpdb;
    $custom_post_type = 'product'; 
    $results = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT ID, post_title FROM {$wpdb->posts} WHERE post_type = %s and post_status = 'publish'", $custom_post_type ), ARRAY_A );
    if ( ! $results )
            return;
            $output = '<ul id="products">';
            foreach( $results as $index => $post ) {
                    $output .= '<li id="' . $post['ID'] . '">' . $post['post_title'] . '</li>';
                }
            $output .= '</ul>'; // end of select element
            return $output;
}
```

But when I try and modify 'post_title' to either of the ACF field values I get no output. Please advise.

Comment: That's because you're querying specifics in the DB... the fields don't exist there. ACF has existing functions to get field values e.g. [get_field()](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/)

Comment: Is it possible to list all field values and not just for a specific post? Most of the examples pass post_id as a parameter.

Comment: Well.. any ACF values you set would be **inside** a post, would it not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you're querying specifics in the DB... the fields don't exist there. ACF has existing functions to get field values e.g. [get_field()](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/)

So in your case:

```
function output_product_list() {
    global $wpdb;
    $custom_post_type = 'product'; 
    $results = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT ID, post_title FROM {$wpdb->posts} WHERE post_type = %s and post_status = 'publish'", $custom_post_type ), ARRAY_A );
    if ( ! $results )
            return;
            $output = '<ul id="products">';
            foreach( $results as $index => $post ) {
                    $output .= '<li id="' . $post['ID'] . '">' . get_field('ACF_FIELD_NAME',$post['ID']) . '</li>';
                }
            $output .= '</ul>'; // end of select element
            return $output;
}
```

Be sure to change the `ACF_FIELD_NAME` to what ever you named the ACF field in the WP Admin

Comment: `the_field()` will output directly, you want get_field() here.

Comment: Noted, changed.

Answer (score 1):

```
function output_product_list() {
    global $wpdb;
    $custom_post_type = 'product'; 
    $results = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT ID, post_title FROM {$wpdb->posts} WHERE post_type = %s and post_status = 'publish'", $custom_post_type ), ARRAY_A );
    $res_count = count($results);
    if($res_count > 0){
        $output = '<ul id="products">';
        foreach( $results as $index => $post ) {
                $output .= '<li id="' . $post['ID'] . '">' . get_field('ACF_FIELD_NAME',$post['ID']) . '</li>';
            }
        $output .= '</ul>'; // end of select element
        echo $output;
     }
}
```